# "Ignoring exception in command None: discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "hi" is not found" on Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I have this thing that I would like to fix. I use two separate programs because they work on two different computers, and also because one uses "on_message" and the other uses "@ bot.commands". When I use the "on_message" part the other program says: "Ignoring exception in command None: discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "hi" is not found ". The problem is that I want the Python console clean! Anyone know how to do it?

Comment: Create an error handler (the on_command_error event) and ignore that type of exception. This example from the Discord.py Discord server should help you out: https://gist.github.com/EvieePy/7822af90858ef65012ea500bcecf1612

Comment: If I understand correctly, make `on_command_error` and have it ignore all instances of exceptions from `CommandNotFound`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added this in the Bot's Program and it worked! Thank you Eric Jin for the answer!

```
@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, command):
    pass
```